# Text processing

Tags: r, logic, text-mining

I am having issues in coming up with the right algorithm to identify blocks of strings that are followed by empty strings.

For example:

I have

```
x1 <- c("hello","c1","","","hello","c2","3","","hello","","c1","c2","")
```

And I want to collapse each block of strings that are seperated by empty strings to make it look like this one below:

```
c("hello c1","hello c2 3","hello","c1 c2")
```

The cells that come right after one another are meant to be together, that is why I need to join those that have no empty cell in between them.

I tried several approaches with ifelse statements and for loops with mixed results. I get there somewhat but always end up with duplicates. Another issue is that I have trouble identifying blocks that span over more than 2 lines. One of the flawed approaches was:

```
i <- which(x1 != "")
cells <- c()

for (j in 1:length(i)) {
  cells[j] <- ifelse((i[j] - i[j+1]) == -1, yes = paste(x1[i[j]], no = x1[i[j+1]]), paste(x1[i[j]]))
}

cells
```

The output then is:

`"hello c1" "c1"       "hello c2" "c2 3"     "3"        "hello"    "c1 c2"    NA`

I don't mind the NA, but already in the first two entries I have "c1" mentioned twice. I know why...the algorithm is flawed, but I cant figure out the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. Find the separator positions.
2. Subset the string along these separators.
3. Paste these subsets together.

```r
x1 <- c("hello","c1","","","hello","c2","3","","hello","","c1","c2","")

## 1. Find the separator positions
idx <- which(!nzchar(x1))

## 2. Get subset start end end positions
sbs <- cbind(c(0L, head(idx, -1L)), idx)

## 3. Paste these subsets together.
(res <- apply(sbs,
              1L,
              \(r) paste(x1[(r[1L] + 1L):(r[2L] - 1L)], collapse = " ")))

# [1] "hello c1"   " "          "hello c2 3" "hello"      "c1 c2"
```

*N.B.* There is a `" "` string in the result, which technically makes sense, b/c in your sample you have two delimiters next to each other. If you want to filter it out you can do:

```r
res[nzchar(trimws(res))]
# [1] "hello c1"   "hello c2 3" "hello"      "c1 c2"
```

Comment: that looks exactly like what I need thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped. If it worked, would you mind accepting/upvoting the answer?